# File variables persisting between separate functions in C

Tags: c

I have a straight forward c file that creates a simple tree with 3 possible children for each node. My goal is to find the sum of the data within a given node and all of its children. I am doing this with recursion and it works one time but then when it gets ran twice in a row the value of the old method is staying and I am not sure why. Meaning when it is called again the two data values are added instead of it just resetting to 0 like I have at the top of the class. Not sure why this is happening. Here is the code.

```
struct N *mknode(struct N *xp, struct N *yp, struct N *zp, long n)
{
struct N *p = malloc(sizeof(struct N));
p->x = xp;
p->y = yp;
p->z = zp;
p->data = n;
return p;
}

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
struct N *p1, *p2, *p3, *p4, *p5, *p6;

// construct a tree for testing:

p1 = mknode(NULL, NULL, NULL, 1);
p2 = mknode(NULL, NULL, NULL, 10);
p3 = mknode(NULL, NULL, NULL, 100);
p4 = mknode(p1, p2, p3, 3000);
p1 = mknode(NULL, NULL, NULL, 1);
p2 = mknode(NULL, NULL, NULL, 10);
p3 = mknode(NULL, NULL, NULL, 100);
p5 = mknode(p1, p2, p3, 4000);
p5 = mknode(p4, p5, NULL, 50000);
p6 = mknode(p5, NULL, NULL, 100000);

// to test only on trees, remove the following
// assignments that turn the tree into a graph
//p1->x = p5;
//p2->y = p4;
//p2->z = p2;
//p6->y = p5;
//p6->z = p6;

long s = sum(p6);
long x = sum(p6);
```

s and x should have the same value but x is double s for some reason.
This is the function code in a separate class.

```
long data = 0;

long sum(struct N *p){
printf("%ld\n", data);
if (p != NULL){
    sum(p->x);
    sum(p->y);
    sum(p->z);
    return data += p->data;
}
return 0;
}
```

Here is the initial struct in a header file.

```
struct N {
struct N *x;
struct N *y;
struct N *z;
long data;
};
```

Comment: `long data = 0;` That's an initializer. It only sets the value once upon program startup. Move it into the function to have it initialise as a local variable each time the function is executed.

Comment: C does not have classes.

Comment: And note that C does not have "classes" nor "methods". You probably mean "file" and "function".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sum` adds to the *global* variable `data`. After each call from `main`, it is never reset to zero.

Between each call to `sum` in `main`, add `data = 0;`. Or better yet, rewrite `sum` as:

```
long
sum(struct N *p)
{
    long total = 0;
    if (p != NULL){
        total += sum(p->x);
        total += sum(p->y);
        total += sum(p->z);
        total += p->data;
    }
    return total;
}
```

Then, just print the return value of `sum`

Comment: Thank you for the solution and for clarifying why it is happening.